# Check if element class contains string using playwright

Tags: javascript, dom, playwright

I am trying to get the element of day 18, and check if it has *disabled* on its class.

```
<div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--tue" aria-label="day-16" role="option">16</div>
<div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--wed react-datepicker__day--today" aria-label="day-17" role="option">17</div>
<div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--thu react-datepicker__day--disabled" aria-label="day-18" role="option">18</div>
```

this is my code, assume

```
this.xpath = 'xpath=.//*[contains(@class, "react-datepicker__day") and not (contains(@class, "outside-month")) and ./text()="18"]'
```

```
  async isDateAvailable () {
    const dayElt = await this.page.$(this.xpath)
    console.log(dayElt.classList.contains('disabled'))) \\this should return true
```

I can't seem to make it work. Error says TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined. Can you help point what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to evaluate it inside the browser. `$` will return an ElementHandle which is a wrapper around the browser DOM element, so you have to use e.g. `evaluate` then on it. Or simply `$eval` which will lookup the element, pass it into a callback which gets executed inside the browsers JavaScript engine. This means something like that would work:

```
// @ts-check
const playwright = require("playwright");

(async () => {
  const browser = await playwright.chromium.launch();
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const page = await context.newPage();
  await page.setContent(`
      <div id="a1" class="foo"></div>
    `)
  console.log(
    await page.$eval("#a1", el => el.classList.contains("foo1"))
  )
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 16):

Looks like you can just write

```js
await expect(page.locator('.selector-name')).toHaveClass(/target-class/)
```

`/target-class/` - slashes is required because it's RegExp

For check few classes by one a call I use this helper (It's because api way doesn't work for me https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions#locator-assertions-to-have-class):

```
async function expectHaveClasses(locator: Locator, className: string) {
    // get current classes of element
    const attrClass = await locator.getAttribute('class')
    const elementClasses: string[] = attrClass ? attrClass.split(' ') : []
    const targetClasses: string[] = className.split(' ')
    // Every class should be present in the current class list
    const isValid = targetClasses.every(classItem => elementClasses.includes(classItem))

    expect(isValid).toBeTruthy()
}
```

In `className` you can write few classes separated by space:

```
const result = await expectHaveClasses(page.locator('.item'), 'class-a class-b')
```

Comment: There is native solution for that: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-have-class

Comment: @TadasV. yes, I provided this link too, but in the documentation, you can see this note: "Note that if array is passed as an expected value, entire lists of elements can be asserted:". When I tried the way with an array of classes - it required providing all classes on the element, but I wanted to check only a few.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding OP's original code, XPath is generally not the recommended approach for selecting elements in Playwright. Prefer locators. I'd probably select by text and role, then assert the class(es) are present. Then again, classes aren't [user-visible](https://playwright.dev/docs/best-practices#test-user-visible-behavior), so there's probably a better assertion opportunity there as well.

If Playwright test is out of the picture as appears to be the case for OP, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66241301/6243352) correctly provides an `evaluate`, although I'd write it with a locator:

```js
const isDisabled = await page.getByLabel("day-18")
  .evaluate(el => el.classList.contains("disabled"));
```

---

Treating this thread as a canonical for asserting element classes, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71740724/6243352) nicely shows how to use regex to match a single class, but also advocates an [antipattern](https://playwright.dev/docs/best-practices#use-web-first-assertions) in its `expectHaveClasses` helper:

```js
const isValid = targetClasses.every(classItem => elementClasses.includes(classItem))
expect(isValid).toBeTruthy()
```

The problem is that the error message on failure will be unclear and potentially difficult to debug. Furthermore, the assertion won't wait for the class to change to the correct one in cases when the element is in the DOM but will have its class list adjusted asynchronously.

Class lists are usually not that long, so I would enumerate each class name separately:

```js
const loc = page.locator("p")
await expect(loc).toHaveClass(/\bfoo\b/);
await expect(loc).toHaveClass(/\bbar\b/);
await expect(loc).toHaveClass(/\bbaz\b/);
```

It's a good case where WET and avoiding premature abstraction is probably better than [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), since the bar for correctly DRYing out the code is fairly high.

Technically, lookaheads are also possible:

```js
await expect(loc).toHaveClass(/(?=.*\ba\b)(?=.*\bb\b)(?=.*\bc\b)/);
```

But this is unreadable, so if you're going to do this, then a helper might make sense:

```js
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.30.0

test.beforeEach(({page}) => page.setContent('<p class="a b c d"></p>'));

const hasWordsRegex = (...a) =>
  new RegExp(a.map(e => `(?=.*\\b${e}\\b)`).join(""));

test("has classes 'a', 'b' and 'c'", async ({page}) => {
  await expect(page.locator("p")).toHaveClass(hasWordsRegex("a", "b", "c"));
});
```

Note that this isn't strict, so it's OK that class `d` is present. That's the common case.

If you're really serious about this pattern, you can put it into a custom matcher:

```js
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.30.0

test.beforeEach(({page}) => page.setContent('<p class="a b c d"></p>'));

const hasWordsRegex = (...a) =>
  new RegExp(a.map(e => `(?=.*\\b${e}\\b)`).join(""));

expect.extend({
  async toHaveAllClasses(received, ...classes) {
    const className = await received.evaluate(el => el.className);

    if (hasWordsRegex(...classes).test(className)) {
      return {
        message: () => "passed",
        pass: true,
      };
    }

    return {
      message: () =>
        `failed: element class '${className}' ` +
        `did not match expected '${classes.join(" ")}'`,
      pass: false,
    };
  },
});

test("has classes 'a', 'b' and 'c'", async ({page}) => {
  await expect(page.locator("p")).toHaveAllClasses("a", "b", "c");
});

test("is missing at least one of 'a', 'b', 'c' or 'x'", async ({page}) => {
  await expect(page.locator("p")).not.toHaveAllClasses("a", "b", "c", "x");
});
```

Aside from readability, the other issue with regex is forgetting to escape regex special characters. Use caution with regex! In the above example, it may be unclear that regex is being used under the hood, leading to confusing failures. It can be re-written without regex:

```js
expect.extend({
  async toHaveAllClasses(received, ...classes) {
    const [classList, className] =
      await received.evaluate(el => [[...el.classList], el.className]);
    const missing = classes.filter(e => !classList.includes(e));

    if (missing.length) {
      return {
        message: () =>
          `failed: element class '${className}' ` +
          `did not contain '${missing.join(", ")}'`,
        pass: false,
      };
    }

    return {
      message: () => "passed",
      pass: true,
    };
  },
});
```

If you want to fail when extra classes are present, you can add a check in the opposite direction:

```js
const extra = classList.filter(e => !classes.includes(e));

if (extra.length) {
  return {
    message: () =>
      `failed: element class '${className}' ` +
      `had extra class '${extra.join(", ")}' ` +
      `that wasn't part of the expected class '${classes.join(" ")}'`,
    pass: false,
  };
}
```

This lets you check multiple classes exactly, in any order.

The (hopefully) final issue here is that `evaluate` doesn't wait for the class to pass the test--it checks once, immediately, and succeeds or fails.

Something like `waitForFunction`, [polling](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions#polling) or [retrying](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions#retrying) can help create a wait, but hopefully these little annoyances are enough to motivate why using a few `toHaveClass` calls is probably the best solution at the time of writing.