# How to get classList on a selector in playwright?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, playwright

This is my start with playwright and I try to test my React app with it.

It might be that there is a similar question somewhere here, however I've tried all the possible non-specific answers from StackOverflow and Github issues.

This is my test:

```
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test";

test.describe('App general functionality', () => {
    test('Theme switches normally', async ({page}) => {
        const app = await page.getByTestId('app');
        const themeSwitch = await page.getByTestId('themeSwitch');

        const classList = await app.evaluate(node => {
            console.log(node);
        });
        // const classList = await app.getAttribute('class');
    });
});
```

I've tried installing extended expect types for `toHaveClass` and checked if `app` is present. In console it returns locator and elements inside the `app`. App is a test id on the root `div` of the application.

However the error is constant:

```
locator.evaluate: Target closed
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for getByTestId('app')
============================================================
```

And it is one this line:

```js
const classList = await app.evaluate // or app.getAttribute('class')
```

The app div:

```html
<div data-test-id={'app'} className={`app ${appStore.isDarkTheme ? 'dark' : 'light'}`}>
```

[**Git url**](https://github.com/An1mus/merntodo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the test id is set properly. It should be `data-testid` based on the following experiment:

```js
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.30.0

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body><div data-testid="app" class="foo bar baz">hi</div></body></html>`;

test.describe("App general functionality", () => {
  test("Theme switches normally", async ({page}) => {
    await page.setContent(html); // for easy reproducibility
    const el = await page.getByTestId("app");
    const classList = await el.evaluate(el => [...el.classList]);
    expect(classList).toEqual(["foo", "bar", "baz"]);
  });
});
```

If you can't change the element's property, maybe try

```js
const el = await page.$('[data-test-id="app"]');
```

Pehaps a bit more idiomatic (assuming you've fixed `testid`):

```js
const app = page.getByTestId("app");
await expect(app).toHaveClass(/\bfoo\b/);
await expect(app).toHaveClass(/\bbar\b/);
await expect(app).toHaveClass(/\bbaz\b/);
```

This handles extra classes and different ordering of the classes. See also [Check if element class contains string using playwright](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76038252/6243352) for deeper discussion of this pattern.

Comment: I've deleted previous comments because I've discovered, that test doesn't actually open the necessary page. I need to put page.goto(URL) so chromium will open the necessary page. For some reason it ignores baseURL in the playwright.config.

Comment: Eventually after navigating to the page and using exported `expect` this worked for me, thank you.