# How to expect an element to have a specific string it the class attribute

Tags: typescript, playwright

I would like check if an element has a specific string it the class attribute.
The `toHaveClass` assertion looks promising but does not seem to allow to check for one specific class string.

Assuming the following element `<div class="a b">`, I would like to check for `a` using `await expect(myLocator).toHaveClass('a')` but this does not work because the api would expect class to be "a b".

Is there is simple way to exist an element to have one specific string in its class list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Regex if you want to do a partial match, see: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-have-class

Answer (score 1):

If you're testing with regex as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76034150/6243352), make sure to use `\b` for word boundaries:

```js
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.30.0

test("has class 'a'", async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent('<div class="a b"></div>');
  await expect(page.locator("div")).toHaveClass(/\ba\b/);
});

test("does not have class 'a'", async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent('<div class="aaa b"></div>');
  await expect(page.locator("div")).not.toHaveClass(/\ba\b/);
});
```

Without the word boundaries, test 2 would fail, detecting the class `a` as a substring of `aaa`.

See also [How to get classList on a selector in playwright?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75393063/6243352) and [Check if element class contains string using playwright](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76038252/6243352) which show how to test multiple classes in any order.

Comment: Using RegEx does work but I personally do not like messing around with string when there could be a clean solution based on the classList property in the DOM.

Comment: I agree, regex is dangerous since you can forget about escaping a special character. The verbosity is ugly. I have a long answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76038252/6243352) that shows my best attempt to work around it, but I think at the end of the day the `\b`s are probably the least-bad approach as shown in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can still use [toHaveClass](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-have-class):

```
await expect(locator).toHaveClass('a b');
```

toHaveClass allows string as well in its function arguments.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

(Tested!!) To verify presence of an string inside class property of locator:

```
let className= await this.page.$eval(locator, element => element.className)
  console.log("className--> "+className)
  await expect(className).toContain('SOMETHING')
```